# Sign up to a new site via the network Open ID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I was trying to join the new Emacs site.

I saw an apparently strange behaviour during sign up.

If try to sign up via Google (being logged to it), I get a prompt asking whether I accept SE to see my mail and some basic profile info. All I have to do is to click accept.

If try to sign up using Stack Exchange (being logged to it), I am asked a (new) email address, name, password, etc.

What for? I have already a network profile, why not asking me to use that?
I don't remember when I signed up last time, but it was much simpler: just granting permission to SE Open ID.

Comment: My situation is different. His problem is the annoyance of *re-enter* his network Open ID id/password. In my case, I am *not* offered to sign up with my *existing* Open ID network account at all. I am asked to create a *new account*, (new email, new password etc).